# Почему Observable не является интерфейсом?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Почему в java Observable является именно классом, а не интерфейсом?

Comment: Потому что он уже реализован?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Единственная причина для существования класса — хранить два поля: флаг и список наблюдателей. Интерфейс нестатичные поля содержать не может.

Почему он так называется? По смыслу: «наблюдаемый» объект. То, что название напоминает интерфейс скорее всего случайно.

Надо заметить что [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) — старый класс который практически не изменился со своего появления в JDK 1.0 (для сравнения [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) появился в 1.1). Начиная с Java 9, класс отмечен как @Deprecated. Класс выполняет свою задачу, но, пожалуй, не является хорошим примером как ООП, так и именования классов.